# Restore Pop Up Window in OpenOffice won't go away

Tags: openoffice.org, restore

I have been using OpenOffice for months.  Now when I open up the application, I get a pop up window with the message that "`The application Open Office quit unexpectedly while trying to restore its window. Do you want to try to restore its window again?`"  When I click restore, nothing happens, when I click don't restore, nothing happens, and I am not able to use or quit the program because the window remains.  I have trashed the application and re-downloaded it, same problem.

Comment: Do you mean Libre Office or did you actually install Open Office?

Comment: Which version of **Ubuntu**? Do you have **LibreOffice**, **OpenOffice**, or ***both*** on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using the newer libreoffice. For openoffice the procedure will be similar, but the names and directories will be different.

It sounds like some setting kept in one of the hidden files used by libreoffice is troubling the program. More specifically the software knows about a document which it needs to recover but has trouble doing.

libreoffice puts settings in a directory libreoffice, which sits in .config in your user's directory.
if you start a terminal and issue `ls .config/libreoffice` you should see some result (on my computer i get a directory named `3`).

By issuing the command `mv ~/.config/libreoffice ~/.config/libreoffice_BAK` and then restarting libreoffice, libreoffice should start with a clean slate and at least should allow you to use it.

PS. for openoffice i believe the settings directory may be located in ~/.openoffice but this could also be ~/.config/openoffice